# I can send emails from a smart contract?

Tags: solidity, remix, ethers.js, proof-of-authority, authentication

For security, i need to generate a smart contract from authentication and the way that was solicited is use email and send a token to this email, so i think i can generate a token in my smart contract and send it to the mail to ensure that anyone can see it from anywhere, is this posible?, that i send the token directly from the smart contract or i need to pass it to a server and the serve send the token to an email?

Comment: Smart contracts cannot communicate with the outside world.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot send emails from an Smart Contract. You can even connect with any kind of external source of information (API or whatever). To do so, you must implement an oracle system like Chainlink.

Check out this link to make API calls (to an email service provider, in your case, for example): https://docs.chain.link/any-api/introduction/

Comment: Thanks, instead a solution called blockchain2mail that was close in 2021 allow you to send mails. Instead i will create a server for the email transfer i search and is the best solution